# How to add a set of suggestions into the setSuggestions

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using the Material `SearchView` which is provided by the library `'com.miguelcatalan:materialsearchview:1.4.0'`. This library uses `setSuggestions` to set suggestions into the search view like i shown in the following code. But the setSuggestions  allows `String[]` only. I want to load a list of items from the firebase and put in to the suggestion. The problem is that setSuggestion does not allow `ArrayList`.

```
materialSearchView.setOnSearchViewListener(new MaterialSearchView.SearchViewListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSearchViewShown() {
            //Do some magic
            mProgress.setMessage("Loading...");
            mProgress.show();
            mDatabasePlaces.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    for (DataSnapshot data:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){


                        Place models=data.getValue(Place.class);

                        placelist.add(models.getName());

                    }
                    mProgress.dismiss();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });



            materialSearchView.setSuggestions(placelist);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSearchViewClosed() {
            //Do some magic
        }
    });



}
```

In the code placelist is an `ArrayList` which is not allowed in the  `materialSearchView.setSuggestions(placelist);` So how can I put that list of places into `setSuggestions`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can parse it to `String[]` like this

```
 String[] parsedArray = placelist.toArray(new String[placelist.size()])
```

Answer (score 1):

Due the asynchronous behavior of `onDataChange` method, to get your work done, please move the following line of code:

```
materialSearchView.setSuggestions(placelist);
```

Inside `onDataChange` method right after this line of code:

```
mProgress.dismiss();
```

As also Artur Akhnoyan mentioned in his answer, please change the argument from `placelist` to:

```
placelist.toArray(new String[placelist.size()])
```